# C/C++ and Fortran writing to same file

Tags: c++, c, fortran

I have a C/C++ library whose functions are called inside a Fortran program.
I would like to write some output generated in my library on the same file the Fortran program  outputs to.
I tried to pass the filename, open it in C++, write to it and finally close it with this sample code:

```
std::ofstream output;
output.open(name, ofstream::out | ofstream::app);

/*
   Some calculations...
 */    

output << "Result is " << result << std::endl;

output.close();
```

Nothing is written to file, unless I remove ofstream::app but then most part of what is written by the Fortran code is destroyed...
I also tried using fprintf with a similar sample code:

```
FILE * pFile = fopen(name, "a");

 /*
   Some calculations...
 */    

fprintf(pFile, "Result is = %.10E", result);

fclose(pFile);
```

with the same results. Any clue as to how to do this?

Comment: Did you check if the file is correctly open ?

Comment: As Vladimir said, it's quite dangerous. However, you can do that (relatively) safely if you close in one "language" before opening (for append) in the other. The standard way to append in Fortran 90 is opening with *position="append"*. Here, close you file in Fortran before calling your C++ function, and upon return, reopen for append if you need to write again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even if you find a way how to do that for one set of runtime libraries, it may fail for another (e.g., different compiler collection) or another operating system... Do not do that, pass the data you want to write to the part of the system that opened the file originally.

Comment: I tried arbautjc suggestion and it works, but I agree with you it's definitely not safe to do this kind of meddling.

Comment: If the file is actually closed before opening by the different runtime library, I have no objections, that should work. Make sure to close it again before opening it again in the original code.